# Is a video from or by a CCTV camera?

Tags: prepositions

For instance, here's a sentence

> As shown in the video from a CCTV camera, [clause].

Is it okay? I'm also not completely sure about *"**in** the video"*. You say *"**in** the movie"* or *"**in** the book"* so it's logical, at first sight. However, you release something *"**on**"* video or upload something *"**on**"* the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... shown in the video ...

That is fine.

"By" would work if you said something like this

> This video has been recorded **by** a CCTV camera on the corner of ...
>
> *"The footage showed Chang purposely lowering his head to avoid being captured on video **by** the CCTV in the lift." - google*

In your sentence, "from" is the the appropriate choice.

> *"The video from the CCTV cameras show how the shells fall into the oil tanks ..." - google*

If you wanted to avoid the use of "from/by" in your sentence, you could rewrite it like this

> "As shown in the CCTV footage, ..." or "As can be seen in the CCTV footage, ..."

Answer (score 0):

“From” should be used to explain the source of the video.

“On video” means a video is the type of record—not a book.

“Upload to” a specific site.

“In a video” means there may be other content.

Otherwise it would be better to say, “the video shows” something